# Java does not allow me to return ArrayList of Strings from a function of return type ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Java allows me to return a String from a function of return type Object but it does not allow me to return ArrayList of Strings from a function of return type ArrayList of Objects

in the second function if java can check at runtime that s is an object .Then why cant it check that ArrayList of Strings is actually an ArrayList of Objects.

Comment: That's because generics are not covariant. This question has been asked before, try searching around for it.

Comment: +1 to @arshajii. He should write this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

That's why Java has Generics, image this case:

```
public ArrayList<Object> hola(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

it even won't pass the compiler because compiler is expecting an ArrayList that accept "Objects" not String, also generics was created to avoid the use of casting and to help the programmer in compile time to check if whats inside the collection is the same type its meant to hold. You might think it violate the point of Polymorphism but it doesn't really, using `Generic Class` help alot if you think about it in a positive way.

If you want to do something like that you would have to do this way:

```
public <T extends Object> ArrayList<T> take(ArrayList<T> list){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

That's the correct way doing it, the `<T extends Object>` mean accept an Object that is subclass of Object, so it'd accept everything because all the classes are subclass of Object.

Comment: Why? he wanted to know why

Comment: `<T extends Object>` is also redundant---what else would it extend? Just `<T>` has the same meaning.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  Are you sure? without <T extends Object> it won't compile, it doesn't for me, and i returned new ArrayList<String>() and worked for me.

Comment: I am quite sure, and [here is the objective proof](https://ideone.com/HihhpT). [And more proof](https://ideone.com/4Ai24f), this one showing what does compile.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, sorry, i fixed the answer with new ArrayList<T>(). @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 0):

As @arshaji said, generics are not covariant; for a quick definition of covariance, see [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Formal_definition).

What it means is that while:

```
Object < String
```

It is NOT true that:

```
List<Object> < List<String>
```

This is because of **type erasure**. At runtime, a `List<Whatever>` becomes a `List` (for backwards compatibility reasons): the type information of elements of the `List` in code are lost at runtime.

In essence, and while not technically accurate, this Java 5+ code:

```
for (final String s: listOfStrings)
    doSomethingWith(s);
```

is equivalent, at runtime, to this Java 4- code:

```
for (final Object o: listOfStrings)
    doSomethingWith((String) o); // note the cast
```

Comment: Hm... type erasure is not the culprit here, actually---it's basic logic. "A list of strings" simply *isn't* substitutable for the concept "a list of objects". Otherwise any operation you can perform on the latter would be allowed on the former, which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was rather thinking along the lines of "array vs Collection" here... After all these years of doing Java 5+, it seems I still cannot give a proper explanation, eh? :/

Comment: No wonder... generics are so incongruent with everything Java had before them, it's quite distasteful.

Comment: On the other hand, it's actually generics which are correct, and arrays which aren't. However, mixing both paradigms into almost the same language concept (array/list) is not right.

Answer (score 0):

> why cant it check that ArrayList of Strings is actually an ArrayList of Objects.

Its because although `String` IS-AN `Object`, `ArrayList<String>` IS-NOT `ArrayList<Object>`. You cannot do the following in Java:

```
ArrayList<Object> objs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It means that `ArrayList<String>` cannot be assigned to an `ArrayList<Object>`. Even though at runtime the type of `Arraylist` is erased, you cannot assign one type of `ArrayList` to another type at compile time.

If you want your method to return an `ArrayList` of any `Object`, then you can change your method signature to:

```
public ArrayList<? extends Object> methodName()
{
    //.. Your code here
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```